# ftp_get will not download image

Tags: php, ftp

```
    $fp = 'test.png';
    $server_file = "dir/testing.png";

    //-- Connection Settings
    $ftp_server = 'ftp.net';; // Address of FTP server.
    $ftp_user_name ='user'; // Username
    $ftp_user_pass = 'password'; // Password

    // set up basic connection
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,21);

    // login with username and password
   $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);       
   $mode = ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);

   $download=ftp_get($conn_id, $fp, $server_file, FTP_BINARY);
    // try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
    if ( $download) {
        echo "Successfully $fp\n";

    } else {
        echo "There was a problem\n";
    }

    ftp_close($conn_id);
```

When I run this it says it is successfully, but will not write or download the file.
If I `echo file_get_contents($fp);` then it will display the image deconstructed into text [in the Web browser]

In need to download images and video...

Comment: Sorry, it currently is impossible to make sense from your question. Please explain what you mean by "then it will display the image deconstructed into text the bowers.".

Comment: Check the permissions of your target folder and if the folder exists i.e. the dir/testing.png

Comment: when it opens in the bowers it looks like

‰PNG  IHDRRRÇ,ƒ› pHYsšœ OiCCPPhotoshop ICC profilexÚSgTSé=÷ÞôBKˆ€”KoR RB‹€‘&*! Jˆ!¡ÙQÁEEÈ ˆŽŽ€ŒQ,Š Øä!¢Žƒ£ˆŠÊûá{£kÖ¼÷æÍþµ×>ç¬ó³ÏÀ–H3Q5€©BàƒÇÄÆáä.@ $p³d!sý#ø~<<+"À¾xÓÀM›À0‡ÿêB™\€„Àt‘8K€@zŽB¦@F€˜&S `ËcbãP-`

i can download in cyberduck fine.. so i thing the permissions are okay

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```